# How to create video from ARKit face session depth pixel buffer

Tags: ios, arkit, truedepth-camera

I'm trying to append `frame.capturedDepthData.depthDataMap` to `AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor` but the result is always unsuccessful.

My adaptor is configured like this:

```
NSError* error;
videoWriter = [AVAssetWriter.alloc initWithURL:outputURL fileType:AVFileTypeMPEG4 error:&error];
if (error)
{
    NSLog(@"Error creating video writer: %@", error);
    return;
}

NSDictionary* videoSettings = @{
        AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecTypeH264,
        AVVideoWidthKey: @640,
        AVVideoHeightKey: @360
};

writerInput = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo outputSettings:videoSettings];
writerInput.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);

NSDictionary* sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary = @{
        (NSString*) kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey: @(kCVPixelFormatType_DepthFloat32)
};

adaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor
        assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:writerInput
                                   sourcePixelBufferAttributes:sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary];

if ([videoWriter canAddInput:writerInput])
{
    [videoWriter addInput:writerInput];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Error: cannot add writerInput to videoWriter.");
}

[videoWriter startWriting];
[videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];
```

and then on every `session:(ARSession*)session didUpdateFrame:(ARFrame*)frame` callback I try to append depth pixel buffer like this:

```
if (!adaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData)
{
    NSLog(@"Asset input writer is not ready for more media data!");
}
else
{
    if (frame.capturedDepthData.depthDataMap != NULL)
    {
        frameCount++;
        CVPixelBufferRef pixelRef = frame.capturedDepthData.depthDataMap;
        BOOL result = [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:frame.capturedDepthData.depthDataMap withPresentationTime:CMTimeMake(frameCount, 15)];
    }
}
```

but the result from appending pixel buffer is always FALSE.

Now, if I try to append `frame.capturedImage` to a properly configured adaptor, that will always succeed and that's how I'm currently making a video file from front camera.

But I wonder how can I make video from depth pixel buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to convert depthDataMap pixel buffer to a pixel buffer valid for appending to adaptor:

```
- (void) session:(ARSession*)session didUpdateFrame:(ARFrame*)frame
{
    CVPixelBufferRef depthDataMap = frame.capturedDepthData.depthDataMap;

    if(!depthDataMap)
    {
        // no depth data available
        return;
    }

    CIImage* image = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:depthDataMap];
    CVPixelBufferRef buffer = NULL;
    CVReturn err = PixelBufferCreateFromImage(image, &buffer);

    [adaptorDepth appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:CMTimeMake(frameDepthCount, 15)] // 15 is number of fps
}


CVReturn PixelBufferCreateFromImage(CIImage* ciImage, CVPixelBufferRef* outBuffer) {
    CIContext* context = [CIContext context];

    NSDictionary* attributes = @{ (NSString*) kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey: @YES,
                                  (NSString*) kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey: @YES
    };

    CVReturn err = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                       (size_t) ciImage.extent.size.width, (size_t) ciImage.extent.size.height,
                                       kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef _Nullable) (attributes),
                                       outBuffer);
    if (err)
    {
        return err;
    }

    if (outBuffer)
    {
        [context render:ciImage toCVPixelBuffer:*outBuffer];
    }

    return kCVReturnSuccess;
}
```

The key is in `PixelBufferCreateFromImage` method which is able to create a valid pixel buffer from `CIImage` from original depth pixel buffer.

Comment: can you please recode with swift, cuz I faced some issues when convert it.